# How do I write a SQL statement for this question?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

`CHAMPIONS` (~500 rows)

```
YEAR COUNTRY NAME             ROLE
2018 France  Didier Deschamps Manager
2018 France  Hugo Lloris      Goalkeeper
2018 France  Paul Pogba       Midfielder
2014 Germany Joachim Loew     Manager
2014 Germany Mesut Ozil       Midfielder
2014 Germany Miroslav Klose   Forward
2002 Brazil  Da Silva         Midfielder
1994 Brazil  Da Silva         Midfielder
1998 France  Didier Deschamps Midfielder
```

Write a query showing how many times each country has won the world cup for countries winning the world cup at least twice.

What I am confused about is, the how many times each country has won it, when for example there is France 3 times in 2018. I'm not sure if i need a count option or select statement.

I'd be grateful for extra clarification and help with this, or if my query needs any tweaking.

What I have tried:

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT YEAR, COUNTRY
FROM CHAMPIONS
WHERE COUNTRY>=2;
```

I hope this is right.

Comment: Hint: Look up `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: select country,count(*) from champions group by country having count(*)>2

Comment: I don't think it is possible to win the world cup three times in one year.  You need to better understand your data.

Comment: You should tag the correct RDBMS you are using - are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

You have to count the distinct years per country, like so:

```
SELECT COUNTRY, COUNT(DISTINCT [YEAR]) AS WON
    FROM CHAMPIONS
    GROUP BY COUNTRY
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [YEAR]) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get all champions, then it's obvious that you can't have more then one champion at a time. I would focus on role... Let's say that you only count managers... Example:

```
 select country,count(*) from champions where role='Manager' group by country,role having count(*)>=2
```